# How do I include duplicates? Tried HAVING

Tags: sql, duplicates, having

I am trying to learn SQL, and I am doing a project based on a provided database about past Superbowls. I wrote the below code to try to return a "yes" or "no" (to show I know how to use CASE) in a new column for teams that beat their opponents by more than 14 points. It worked, in a sense, but only returned each winning team once, AKA removed duplicates for teams that have won multiple times, but I want it to return all duplicates to show all games, HELP! I tried a HAVING clause, but I didn't really know what to put...

> display which teams have beaten their opponents by >=14 points

I have Tried this below query:

```
SELECT Winner, Winner_Pts, Loser, Loser_Pts,Date,
    CASE
        WHEN (AVG(Winner_Pts-Loser_Pts) >= 14) THEN "yes"
        ELSE "no"
        END as "won_by_more_than_14"
FROM superbowls
GROUP BY Winner
ORDER BY Winner_Pts DESC
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a need for any aggregation/group by here. You should just be able to populate the won_by column with the `CASE` but without the `AVG()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario, there is no need to aggregate your data in order to find teams that have beaten their opponents by >= 14 points.

If you remove your `AVG` function and `GROUP BY` aggregation, you will return teams that have won the super bowl (and more than once); otherwise, your `CASE` statement is correct.

```
SELECT Winner, 
       Winner_Pts, 
       Loser, 
       Loser_Pts,
       Date,
       CASE 
          WHEN (Winner_Pts-Loser_Pts) >= 14 THEN "Yes"
          ELSE "No"
       END AS "won_by_more_than_14"
FROM superbowls
ORDER BY Winner_Pts DESC
```

You can even add your `CASE` statement to a `WHERE` clause to only `SELECT` rows for teams than won by more than 14 points.

```
WHERE (CASE 
          WHEN (Winner_Pts-Loser_Pts) >= 14 THEN "Yes"
          ELSE "No"
       END) = "Yes"
```

**Input Data:**

| ID | Number | Winner | Winner_Pts | Loser | Loser_Pts | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LVI | Rams | 23 | Bengals | 20 | 2022-02-13 00:00:00 |
| 2 | LV | Buccaneers | 31 | Chiefs | 9 | 2021-02-07 00:00:00 |
| 3 | LVI | Chiefs | 31 | 49ers | 20 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 |
| 4 | LII | Eagles | 41 | Patriots | 33 | 2018-02-04 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 50 | Broncos | 24 | Panthers | 10 | 2016-02-07 00:00:00 |
| 6 | XLVIII | Seahawks | 43 | Denver | 8 | 2014-02-02 00:00:00 |
| 7 | XXXIV | Rams | 23 | Titans | 16 | 2000-01-30 00:00:00 |
| 8 | LIII | Patriots | 13 | Rams | 3 | 2019-02-03 00:00:00 |
| 9 | LI | Patriots | 34 | Falcons | 28 | 2017-02-05 00:00:00 |

**Output Data:**

| Winner | Winner_Pts | Loser | Loser_Pts | Date | won_by_more_than_14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Seahawks | 43 | Denver | 8 | 2014-02-02 00:00:00 | Yes |
| Eagles | 41 | Patriots | 33 | 2018-02-04 00:00:00 | No |
| Patriots | 34 | Falcons | 28 | 2017-02-05 00:00:00 | No |
| Buccaneers | 31 | Chiefs | 9 | 2021-02-07 00:00:00 | Yes |
| Chiefs | 31 | 49ers | 20 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | No |
| Broncos | 24 | Panthers | 10 | 2016-02-07 00:00:00 | Yes |
| Rams | 23 | Bengals | 20 | 2022-02-13 00:00:00 | No |
| Rams | 23 | Titans | 16 | 2000-01-30 00:00:00 | No |
| Patriots | 13 | Rams | 3 | 2019-02-03 00:00:00 | No |

See Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Uh4IvazA).

**Details:**

Removing the `AVG()` function will get the results you want, but that doesn't mean `AVG()` isn't useful, especially for *sports data*. If you did want to aggregate your data, please see the following:

The `AVG()` function is used to find the average of values over records from a table. `AVG()` belongs to a class of functions known as *aggregate functions*. An aggregate function returns a single computed result over multiple rows:

| Aggregate Function | Example Use Case |
| --- | --- |
| SUM() | Find the sum of points by team. |
| COUNT() | Find the number of bowls by each team. |
| MAX() | Find the highest point value by each team. |
| MIN() | Find the lowest point value by each team. |
| AVG() | Find the average points by team. |

The SQL `GROUP BY` clause is used to group rows together. In most cases, a `GROUP BY` clause has one or more aggregate functions that calculate one or more metrics for the group.

Let's take this example here, I'm simply returning all **Winners** and their points:

```
SELECT 
  Winner,
  Winner_Pts AS 'points'
FROM superbowls
ORDER BY Winner_Pts DESC
```

| Winner | points |
| --- | --- |
| Seahawks | 43 |
| Eagles | 41 |
| **Patriots** | **34** |
| Buccaneers | 31 |
| Chiefs | 31 |
| Broncos | 24 |
| **Rams** | **23** |
| **Rams** | **23** |
| **Patriots** | **13** |

Now let's aggregate it by **Winner** to find the average points:

```
SELECT 
  Winner,
  ROUND(AVG(Winner_Pts)) AS 'avg_points'
FROM superbowls
GROUP BY Winner
ORDER BY ROUND(AVG(Winner_Pts)) DESC
```

| Winner | avg_points |
| --- | --- |
| Seahawks | 43 |
| Eagles | 41 |
| Buccaneers | 31 |
| Chiefs | 31 |
| Broncos | 24 |
| **Patriots** | **24** |
| **Rams** | **23** |

As you can see between the two queries above, the Rams and Patriots only have a single row (`GROUPED BY` *Winner*), and the average is:

> (23+23)/2 = 23 (Rams)

> (13+34)/2 = 23.5 - Rounded to 24 (Patriots)

> (41)/1 = 41 (Eagles)

[Source](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-avg-examples/).

If you want to filter your data using `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING`. This is different from the `WHERE` clause because the `GROUP BY` clause runs after `WHERE` clauses which means that you can only use `WHERE` on “raw” data and not on aggregated values. You need to use `HAVING` on aggregated metrics.

> The primary use of the `HAVING` operation is to filter aggregated data.
> You can use it when you summarize your data with `GROUP BY` into new
> metrics, and you want to select the results based on these new values.

**Example:**

Find teams with *average* winning points greater than 40:

```
SELECT 
  Winner,
  ROUND(AVG(Winner_Pts)) AS 'avg_points'
FROM superbowls
GROUP BY Winner
HAVING ROUND(AVG(Winner_Pts)) > 40
ORDER BY ROUND(AVG(Winner_Pts)) DESC
```

| Winner | avg_points |
| --- | --- |
| Seahawks | 43 |
| Eagles | 41 |

[Source](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-having-clause/).